# How can I define pre/post-increment behavior in Perl objects?

Tags: perl, object, decrement

[`Date::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~yves/Date-Simple-3.02/lib/Date/Simple.pm) objects display this behavior, where `$date++` returns the next day's date.

> Date::Simple objects are immutable. After assigning $date1 to $date2, no change to $date1 can affect $date2. This means, for example, that there is nothing like a set_year operation, and ***$date++ assigns a new object to $date***.

How can one custom-define the pre/post-incremental behavior of an object, such that `++$object` or `$object--` performs a particular action?

I've skimmed over [perlboot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html), [perltoot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html), [perltooc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltooc.html) and [perlbot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlbot.html), but I don't see any examples showing how this can be done.

Comment: I checked, and apparently this isn't a dupe. +1 for a question that probably should have been up here a long time ago.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want [`overload`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?overload).

```
package Number;

use overload
    '0+'    => \&as_number,
    '++'    => \&incr,
;

sub new {
    my ($class, $num) = @_;

    return bless \$num => $class;
}

sub as_number {
    my ($self) = @_;

    return $$self;
}

sub incr {
    my ($self) = @_;

    $_[0] = Number->new($self->as_number + 1); # note the modification of $_[0]
    return;
}

package main;

my $num = Number->new(5);
print $num      . "\n"; # 5
print $num++    . "\n"; # 5
print ++$num    . "\n"; # 7
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit, cjm; now I know the link-to-docs convention. :)

Comment: +1 Nice example. You may want to make the behavior of `++` non-standard so that others can see/feel the difference

Answer (score 7):

If you look up [perlfaq7](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-do-I-redefine-a-builtin-function%2c-operator%2c-or-method%3f) you'll find that the answer is to use the [overload](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html) pragma, though they probably could have given the FAQ question a better name (in my opinion).

```
package SomeThing;

use overload
  '+' => \&myadd,
  '-' => \&mysub;
```

Basically (assuming `$a` is an object of the `SomeThing` class and `$b` isn't), the above would overload `$a + $b` to be `$a->myadd($b, 0)` and `$b + $a` to `$a->myadd($b, 1)` (that is, the third argument is a boolean meaning "were the arguments to this operator flipped" and the first-argument-is-self syntax is preserved), and the same for `-` and `mysub`.

Read the documentation for the full explanation.

Comment: Huh, that is an awful title for a FAQ. It's also a pretty poor answer. I'll add it to my list of things to fix.